# Setting MultiSelect List to have same css style as other controls

Tags: html, css

This is a seemingly stupid question, but I'm not a pro when it comes to css. I have added a multiselect listbox, but the css file that came with it has completely changed the look of it and it looks different to my other controls - Is there a simple way of inheriting the look of another control? Below is my multiselect css:

```
span.multiselect-native-select {
    position: relative
}
span.multiselect-native-select select {
    border: 0!important;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0)!important;
    height: 1px!important;
    margin: -1px -1px -1px -3px!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    width: 1px!important;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px
}
.multiselect-container {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.multiselect-container .input-group {
    margin: 5px
}
.multiselect-container>li {
    padding: 0
}
.multiselect-container>li>a.multiselect-all label {
    font-weight: 700
}
.multiselect-container>li.multiselect-group label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 700
}
.multiselect-container>li.multiselect-group-clickable label {
    cursor: pointer
}
.multiselect-container>li>a {
    padding: 0
}
.multiselect-container>li>a>label {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 30px
}
.multiselect-container>li>a>label.radio, .multiselect-container>li>a>label.checkbox {
    margin: 0
}
.multiselect-container>li>a>label>input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-bottom: 5px
}
.btn-group>.btn-group:nth-child(2)>.multiselect.btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
.form-inline .multiselect-container label.checkbox, .form-inline .multiselect-container label.radio {
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 40px
}
.form-inline .multiselect-container li a label.checkbox input[type=checkbox], .form-inline .multiselect-container li a label.radio input[type=radio] {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: 0
}
```

Below you can see that the Multiselect listbox looks completely different:
[image]

Below is my control:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
         <section class="col col-6" style="opacity:10">
               <label class="select">
                   @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedDisabilities, Model.DisabilityLists, new { @id = "ddldisabilities", @multiple = "multiple" })
               </label>
         </section>
   </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$('#ddldisabilities').multiselect({
                nonSelectedText: '- - -No Disabilities- - -',
                allSelectedText: 'No option left ...',
                maxHeight: '100%',
                dropUp: true,
                buttonWidth: '100%',
                enableHTML: true
            });
```

Comment: Can you add some of the relevant HTML code?

Comment: Ah yes, that would help. Done :)